# Why can't a file have both a servlet-mapping and jsp-property-group applied to it?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web.xml

It says in the [Oracle webapp documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurejsp.html)

> If a resource matches a URL pattern in both a servlet-mapping and a
>   jsp-property-group, the pattern that is most specific applies
>   (following the same rules as the servlet specification).

Why can't both be applied? Say I don't want a user to go directly to a jsp file, rather have it go through a servlet first, which will then forward that jsp to the user. But I also want that jsp file to have a prelude, coda, etc. Is there a collision here that one of them has to win over the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to hit your JSP, stuff it underneath WEB-INF. The container can see those JSPs, but nothing from outside can.

Then, you'll see, the Servlet will have one URL, while the JSP will have a separate, different URL.

The external URL, the one representing the Servlet, doesn't (necessarily) conflict with the URL for the JSP. You then code up the property group on the JSP file itself.

Your Servlet will do its processing, and then FORWARD to the JSP (it can not REDIRECT, since the JSP is buried in WEB-INF, and the outside world can not see it).

The property group mapping works against the URL of the resource your are FORWARDing to, the JSP.

So, there's no conflict here. Simply two different URLs, one taking the initial request (the Servlet), the other the rendered resource that you FORWARD too.

Comment: so basically, there's no point of including a jsp in a servlet-mapping, because they shouldn't be typing it in. If they do, they'll get an error, not my problem

Comment: I just don't understand why there has to be this rule about it. What kind of problems would arise if they didn't make this priority rule?